# Is Gram-Schmidt process redudant about square full-rank matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, gram-schmidt

I am trying to grasp the concept of Gram-Schmidt process and I have encountered the following logical difficulty:

1. Given a set of $n$ independent vectors, applying GS algorithm upon this set would produce an orthonormal basis that spans the same vector space as the $n$ independent vectors span - I understand this.
2. It seems to me, that if we take a full-rank square matrix, then in that case the column vectors span the entire $n$-th dimensional space. So in that case I was thinking that using Gram-Schmidt is not helpful since there is a trivial orthonormal basis for the vector space, which is the column/row space of the identity matrix of the same dimension.
3. I couldn't find a justification for this wondering anywhere online so my guess is that I am missing something. In addition, I found examples of solutions to exercises in which 3 independent vectors of 3 entries were given and the entire GS algorithm has been used to find an orthonormal basis - And that contradicts the reasoning I have explained in pargraph 2.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that while the columns do span the entire space and are linearly independent, they are not necessarily orthonormal (which is the reason we used GS at the first place). To use GS you always start with a basis for the vector space.

Answer (score 1):

Gram-Schmidt not only supplies an orthonormal basis, it can make sure that the first vector in the basis is a particular vector. With regard to many linear transformations (e.g. rotations, projections), some orthonormal coordinates are nicer than others.